# get value of hidden field via Jinput

Tags: jform, jinput

hello i created a form in front via a plugin
in my tmpl i create a file value_form.php (compatible with the component)

```
<form id="contact-form-'.$formid.'" method="POST" class="form-validate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>
        '.$titleformD.'
        '.$fields_display.'
        '.$consent_field.'
        '.$captcha_html.'
    <div class="form-group control-group submit-button">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="'.JText::_('FLEXI_FIELD_EMAIL_SUBMIT_LABEL_VALUE').'" class="'.$submit_class.'">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="emailtask" value="plg.email.submit" />
    <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="'.$formid.'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="emailauthor" value="'.$addr.'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="itemid" value="'.$item->id.'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="itemtitle" value="'.$item->title.'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="itemalias" value="'.$item->alias.'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="itemauthor" value="'.$item->author.'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="catid" value="'.$item->catid.'" />
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="" />
    '.JHtml::_("form.token").'
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

and i need to get the value in my 'helper' email.php
i do this

```
$id = $jinput->post->get('formid', '', '');
$datas = $jinput->post->get($id, array(), 'array');
```

and to get value

```
$fromemail = $datas['emailfrom'];
```

but this value is already empty i have value of my form if field aren't hidden type ....

[image]

[image]

thanks for any help

Comment: SUPERGLOBALs are keyed by the field's name, not by a substring in the table's `id` attribute.  Why not try to access the hidden input fields' values by `name` attribute?

Comment: hello sorry i don't understand your reply, can you explain more ?

Answer (score 1):

The `$_POST` array structure is determined by the `name` attribute of each field which exists inside of the `<form></form>` tags.

All of the basics are here: https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

The `array` option is appropriate when you have brace-syntax in the field's name to express a nested structure on the field's submission data.  [example](https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput#:%7E:text=Suppose%20you%20have%20a%20form%20like:)

Although Joomla does have `getArray()`, I recommend that you systematically grab the field values individually and include the default value and sanitisation technique when accessing the data.

From docs: `$input->post->get(param_name, default_value, filter);`

In practice:

```
$emailTask   = $input->post->get('emailtask', '', 'CMD');
$formId      = $input->post->get('formid', '', 'WORD');
$emailAuthor = $input->post->get('emailauthor', '', 'RAW'); // because stripping tags can potentially damage fringe case email addresses; use additional sanitisation step before using this value
$itemId      = $input->post->get('itemid', '', 'INT');
$itemTitle   = $input->post->get('itemtitle', '', 'STRING');
$itemAlias   = $input->post->get('itemalias', '', 'STRING');
$itemAuthor  = $input->post->get('itemauthor', '', 'STRING');
$catId       = $input->post->get('catid', '', 'INT');
$return      = $input->post->get('return', '', 'RAW');
```

If your expected post data isn't even making it to the destination where you expect it, then your issue is not in receiving the data, but sending it to the right place.

I don't know what is rendered by:

```
'.$titleformD.'
'.$fields_display.'
'.$consent_field.'
'.$captcha_html.'
```

so I don't know know if there is `<form></form>` inside of your form tags.

Comment: ok cool thanks for explain !
i replace
$fromemail = $datas['emailauthor'];
for
$emailauthor =  htmlspecialchars($_POST['emailauthor']);
And that works !

Comment: If your problem is resolved, you may award the green tick to my answer to inform the system that your question is resolved.

Comment: Also, please take a moment to give yourself a more "human" screenname (unless you prefer to remain anonymous).

Comment: yes sorry i will do this thanks